# Autocomplete TextView in Fragment with PageAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-sqlite, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to autocomplete the text of a TextView Autocomplete from a SQLite database but when income telTrans.setAdapter (adapter) tabs are blank.
The FragmentPageAdapter code is

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int NUM_ITEMS = 4;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String tabLabel = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 1:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
        case 2:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.title_section4);
            break;
        case 3:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.title_section5);
            break;
        }
        return tabLabel;
    }
}
```

And the Fragment code is

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    String[] itemsTelefono;
    String[] itemsCliente;
    AutoCompleteTextView telTrans;

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public int position;

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        position = args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        int tabLayout = 0;

        switch(position){
        case 0:
            tabLayout = R.layout.reportes;
            break;
        case 1:
            tabLayout = R.layout.datosmantenimiento;
            break;
        case 2:
            tabLayout = R.layout.repuestos;
            break;
        case 3:
            tabLayout = R.layout.transporte;
            break;

        }
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout,container,false);

        ConexionSQL usdbh = new ConexionSQL(getActivity(), "DBUsuarios", null, 1);

        db = usdbh.getWritableDatabase();

        itemsTelefono = usdbh.getAllTelefonos(db);
        itemsCliente = usdbh.getAllClientes(db);
        telTrans = (AutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtTelefonoTransporte);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, itemsTelefono);
        telTrans.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The access to the database has no problem.
When I comment telTrans.setAdapter(adapter), the tabs work fine but when its not commented shows:

```
    Exception dispatching input event. 
    Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
```